# Pascals triangle in python?

Tags: python

Ok so I've been working on this for a long time and I cant seem to get it. Our assignment was to make pascal's triangle and center and all that good stuff... But I cant seem to figure it out.

```
def factorial(n):
    if (n <= 1):
        return 1
    else:
         return n * factorial(n-1)

def combination(n, k):
     return int (factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k)))

def pascal_row(row):
     answer = ""
     for entry in range(row+1):
        answer = answer + " " + str(combination(row, entry))
     print answer

def pascal_triangle(rows):
     for row in range(rows):
          pascal_row(row)


 pascal_triangle(10)
```

I know that if I do the last row which is 9 and subtract by the current row and then multiply by three it will give me the right spacing for each row. I'm just not sure how to incorporate that into the code??
If you could help me that would be fantastic!
thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I've been messing around with it for hours, i feel i just need a push in the right direction.  I think its probably simpler than i'm actually making it though.

Comment: Define `right spacing for each row.`.

Comment: Think about how you would space it if you had to describe to someone who to do it - try it with a pencil and paper. You might find `print ' ' * something` to be useful, as well as possibly string format alignment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following. To look up more examples & documentation on string formatting, visit http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

```
print("{:^50}".format(pascal_row(row)))
```

In the above code, `^` centers the string data. The 50 stands for the string length to be taken. (Big enough to encompass the longest string)